# INDEX MATCH not giving me the desired result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a little bit of your help. I am trying the to use INDEX MATCH formula but it is not giving me the desired result. Here is my query.

I have 2 tables. Table 1 is summary sheet and the table 2 is the list of some specific customers. 
In my table Table 1, there is column of customer name and commission amount.

I just want that when there the customer name is entered in customer column and that name is also listed in table 2, simply multiply the column 3 with 10 otherwise it will state 0.

What i have tried is as follows:
IF(MATCH([Customer Name],Table2[Commission],0),[Quantity]*0.1,"0")

It returns the value when the customer name is entered is customer column whose name is also listed in table 2 but it doesn't show 0 when the other customer name is entered whose name is not listed in table 2. Kindly review and help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should not use `IF` like that. `IF` is simply evaluating a statement to determine whether it is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In this case `MATCH` will return `#N/A` (an error) when a match was not found, which causes the expression to stop being evaluated because an error is returned.

There are several ways to deal with this, but you could start by using `ISERROR` to determine whether a match was found.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([Customer Name],Table2[Commission],0)),0,[Quantity]*0.1)
```

Now your function will check whether the `MATCH` was evaluated to be an error. If it is an error, return `0`, otherwise return `[Quantity]*0.1`.

Comment: It is working. I just need to know one thing. In IF statement, i put Quantity *0.10 in true scenario, why r u putting it in false scenario?

Comment: @SalmanKhan: In this case we are checking if the `MATCH` is evaluated to be an error. `IF` it is an error (`TRUE`), then return `0`, otherwise return `[Quantity]*0.1`. You could reverse the logic by using `NOT(ISERROR(...))` instead if you preferred (ie. if it is not an error, return `[Quantity]*0.1`, otherwise return `0`). It may be more obvious if you step through the steps of "Evaluate Formula" and see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me in detail. Thanks a Lot